# Workflow for Data Cleaning and Merging of Multiple Point Vector Layers in QGIS

Tags: layers, merge, overlapping-features, qgis-modeler, workflow

I have multiple point vector layers in shapefile format. Each shapefile contains information of points (longitude and latitude) and datetime (in dd-MM-yyyy format). The problem is that some layers have **overlapping areas** with points from 2 or more layers in the same area.

I would like to clean up these overlapping areas by **removing** the points from the older layer and just keeping the newer points in the overlapping areas. Subsequently, I will merge all the layers after cleaning (as well as those without overlaps) into one layer. However, I am unsure of how to automate the **comparing of newness** between layers and **removing the older** overlapping points.

So far, I have only managed to come up with a model that converts the newer point layer into a polygon>extracting out points of the older layer that is within the polygon>remove these points from older layer with difference>merge 2 layers into one "cleaned" one before merging all the layers. But this is very manual as I have to select and check the layers myself and this model could only handle 2 layers at one go.

What is a better way of improving the automation of the entire process?